# Q: Problems with latexdiff and alignat

Tags: alignat, latexdiff

I've encountered a problem with `latexdiff` and `alignat`. Consider a file called `temp-old.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello this was a test.
\end{document}
```

and a file `temp.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Hello this is a test.
\begin{alignat}{3}
  a& = b &\quad & \text{if} & \quad & x\ne y\\
  c& = d &      & \text{if} &       & x = y
\end{alignat}    
\end{document}
```

Here's what I do:

```
latexdiff temp-old.tex temp.tex > diff.tex
pdflatex diff.tex
```

which gives

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.46 \DIFaddbegin \begin{alignat}{\DIFadd{3}}
```

This error is not surprising because `diff.tex` contains

```
\DIFaddbegin \begin{alignat}{\DIFadd{3}}
  \DIFadd{a}& \DIFadd{= b }&\DIFadd{\quad }& \DIFadd{\text{if} }& \DIFadd{\quad }& \DIFadd{x\ne y}\\
  \DIFadd{c}& \DIFadd{= d }&      & \DIFadd{\text{if} }&       & \DIFadd{x = y
}\end{alignat}
```

When I change this to

```
\DIFaddbegin \begin{alignat}{3}
  \DIFadd{a}& \DIFadd{= b }&\DIFadd{\quad }& \DIFadd{\text{if} }& \DIFadd{\quad }& \DIFadd{x\ne y}\\
  \DIFadd{c}& \DIFadd{= d }&      & \DIFadd{\text{if} }&       & \DIFadd{x = y
}\end{alignat}
```

it compiles successfully.

I found this (resolved) bug report on GitHub: [Environment "alignat" incorrectly parsed](https://github.com/ftilmann/latexdiff/issues/65). Am I doing something obvious wrong or is this simply a bug?

Comment: There os an obvious error in the use of the environment: if you want to have 2 alignment points, you need 3 ampersands: 2 for each of the alignment points, and 1 to introduce each alignment column but the first.

Comment: @Bernard: Good point, in my attempt to have an MWE, I went too far. But the problem remains.